# GUILayout.Button , как сделать активной-неактивной в EditorWindow?

Tags: c#, unity3d, button

Есть кнопка `GUILayout.Button("Обработать json, разместив объекты на карте")` в окне EditorWindow.
Возможно её сделать активной-неактивной?

Код:

```
public class PlacementObjects : EditorWindow
{
    bool startbuttonbool = false;
    ...
    void OnGUI()
    {
                if (startbuttonbool=GUILayout.Button("Обработать json, разместив объекты на карте"))
                {
                    //ProcessJSONPlaceONmap();
                }
    }
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
bool POM;
GUI.backgroundColor = POM?Color.white:Color.black;
if (GUI.Button(new Rect(0, 0, 64, 64), "text")) {
    if (POM) {
        ProcessJSONPlaceONmap();
    }
}
GUI.backgroundColor = Color.white;
```

Comment: Спасибо на самом деле могу поставить , правильный ответ тому  кто первый написал ... ещё и свой тоже выложу

Answer (score 1):

[Disable группы](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EditorGUI.BeginDisabledGroup.html)

```
bool enabled;


EditorGUI.BeginDisabledGroup(!enabled);
if (startbuttonbool=GUILayout.Button("Обработать json, разместив объекты на карте"))
{
    ProcessJSONPlaceONmap();
}
EditorGUI.EndDisabledGroup();
```

Comment: Спасибо на самом деле могу поставить , правильный ответ тому  кто первый написал ... ещё и свой тоже выложу

Answer (score 0):

```
    public class PlacementObjects : EditorWindow
    {
        bool pressedbool = false;
        ...
        void DrawFooter()
        {               
                    if (!pressedbool)
                    {
                        if (GUILayout.Button("Старт"))
                        {
                            pressedbool = true;
                            // ProcessJSONPlaceONmap();
                        }
                    } else {
                        if (GUILayout.Button("Стоп"))
                        {
                            pressedbool = false;
                        }
                    }
        }
    ...
   }
```